# using require statments with if/elseif statements

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, require

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Question: How to fix these if/elseif statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697787/php-question-how-to-fix-these-if-elseif-statements)

Hello is there a way to write if/ elseif statements to display multiple php pages using require statements. I am currently collecting articles from blogs using rss and displaying the links on a web page. How can I display a certain feed depending on an array value selected from a mysql database. Sorry this is a lot, hope I explained my question well. Here is the code on the display page:

```
$query = "SELECT interests FROM signup WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");

$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$result_array[] = $row['interests'];
} if ($result_array[0] = Politics) {
require 'politics.php';
}
```

Comment: please do not ask duplicate questions under multiple accounts, or your account will be suspended. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a single `=` and Politics isn't quoted. Change you last few lines to look like this:

```
if ($result_array[0] == 'Politics') {
  require 'politics.php';
}
```

Also, as a side note, you should be sure to correctly escape the `$username` in your query variable to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is not using comparative equal signs or quotes. It should be as follows:

```
if ($result_array[0] == 'Politics')
```

Answer (score 1):

Smells somewhat of a bad design. You'd be better off storing users in a user table, their interests in a seperate table, and the master list of interests in a 3rd table.

```
user: (id, name, etc...)
user_interests (user_id, interest_id)
interests (id, name, filename)
```

Then you could trivially do something like:

```
SELECT interests.filename, interests.name
FROM interests
RIGHT JOIN user_interests ON interests.id = user_interests.interest_id
```

and

```
while($row = msyql_fetch... ) {
    include($row['filename']);
}
```