# PHP Question: How to fix these if/elseif statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use these if/else if statements to display these php pages. The if/elseif statements allow for the php page to show up. The data is stored in the mysql. How do we get it so that if its already being displayed it only enters once? Thank you. I hope you can help. Sorry this is a little confusing. I just learned English recently.
Thank you.

```
if ($result_array[0] = Politics) {
        require 'news/political.php';
    } elseif ($result_array[0] = Gossip) {
        require 'news/celebgossib';
    }   elseif ($result_array[0] = Entertainment) {
            require 'news/entertainment.php';
        }   elseif ($result_array[0] = Finance) {
                require 'news/finance.php';

            }   elseif ($result_array[0] = Health) {
                    require 'news/health.php';
                }   elseif ($result_array[0] = Leisure) {
                        require 'news/leisure.php';
                    }   elseif ($result_array[0] = Sports) {
                            require 'news/sports.php';
                        }   elseif ($result_array[0] = Tech) {
                                require 'news/tech.php';
                            }   elseif ($result_array[0] = World) {
                                    require 'news/world.php';
                                } else {
                                    echo "There is no interests in your database";
                                }

                                if ($result_array[1] = Politics) {
                                    require 'news/political.php';
                                } elseif ($result_array[1] = Gossip) {
                                    require 'news/celebgossib';
                                }   elseif ($result_array[1] = Entertainment) {
                                        require 'news/entertainment.php';
                                    }   elseif ($result_array[1] = Finance) {
                                            require 'news/finance.php';

                                        }   elseif ($result_array[1] = Health) {
                                                require 'news/health.php';
                                            }   elseif ($result_array[1] = Leisure) {
                                                    require 'news/leisure.php';
                                                }   elseif ($result_array[1] = Sports) {
                                                        require 'news/sports.php';
                                                    }   elseif ($result_array[1] = Tech) {
                                                            require 'news/tech.php';
                                                        }   elseif ($result_array[1] = World) {
                                                                require 'news/world.php';
                                                            } else {
                                                                echo "There is no interests in your database";
                                                            }
```

Comment: do you mean so that if there is an error it passes what the user entered back to the form so he/she does not have to redo everything?

Comment: That hurt my brain. Have you considering using [switch](http://php.net/switch)?

Comment: Basically, if one of the first if statements is true it only enters that one and not the other ones. Are we on the same page now?

Comment: Can you say what the database looks like?

Comment: There is a row for interests and it stores interest inside of there.

Comment: Why are you incrementally indenting your `elseif` statements?

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of a question he posted moments ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697751/using-require-statments-with-if-elseif-statements

Comment: It got messed up when pasting it in here. Sorry.

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen: So he has two accounts?

Comment: No, thats not my account. I swear.

Comment: @Bolt By someone called 'Austin' with a `if` statement missing the correct `==` comparison and no quotes around the value compared against to require something called 'Politics'. Right at the top. Yeah, I'm guessing he has two accounts.

Comment: Nah, thats my friend. Were working on the same project. I swear, we have the same name.

Comment: And neither of you realized the mistake in your if condition? :/

Comment: None of the answers actually worked for us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
$pages = array(
  'Politics' => 'political',
  'Gossip' => 'celebgossib',
   ...
);

$used = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i)
{
   if (array_key_exists($result_array[$i], $pages)
   {
      if (!array_key_exists($result_array[$i], $used))
      {
         # only display this section once
         include 'news/'.$pages[$result_array[$i]].'.php';
         $used[$result_array[$i]] = true;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Nothing to see here.";
   }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do if the page isn't found; or if subsequent records are duplicates.

Comment: Note: Alternatively, you could use `array_unique` up front and skip the whole `$used` thing... it's hard to give advice when I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: or a break after the include to break out of the for loop

Comment: @Damp, that would give different results. Based on the code he provided, he wants to display page #1 even if page #0 is found. But if he doesn't, then you are right, breaking out is the simplest way to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use == instead of =
I don't know what the right side of the statement is, for example Politics. If its not a variable then you should put it in quotes.

Something like this

```
if ($result_array[0] == "Politics") {
        require 'news/political.php';
    }else ...
```

Comment: You should use `strcmp` instead of `==`.

Comment: It still displays multiple "Politics" from the other if statements

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're iterating over an array of options, and including a bunch of set files?

I would try something like the following:

```
switch( TRUE )
{
    case in_array("Politics", $result_array):
        require 'news/political.php';
        break; 

    case in_array("Gossip", $result_array):
        require 'news/celebgossib';
        break;

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: Yeah, that is my favorite thing about PHP switch/case.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: Mine too. Whenever I see a big if/elseif/elseif/elseif/else I always clean it up to a switch(TRUE), it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a switch statement?

```
switch $result_array[0] {
     case 'Politics':     include('politics.php'); break;
     case 'This': include(...); break;
     case 'That': include(....); break;
     default: include('default.php'); break;
}
```

for a loooong set of if/then/else tests with simple "todo" sections, a switch statement is ideal.

Comment: how do we get it so that it won't display a case in switch $result_array[1] then?

Comment: The problem here is that the OP's if statements don't just check `$result_array[0]`.

Comment: Well, if both [0] and [1] basically cover the same thing, then combine the arrays before hand. if they're mutually exclusive, you could instead use the cases to set a filename. if the filename's not set after the swithc exits, then process the [1]